# TypeError: tzinfo argument must be None or of a tzinfo subclass, not type 'type'

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pytest, tzinfo

I am running test for my project in Python and all of them passed, excepted one.

Here is the code of the function:

```
    @botcmd
    def reminder_next():
        today = datetime.now()
        return "\n".join(
            f"Next planning: {Reminder.next_occurance('Sprint planning', today)}",
            f"Next daily: {Reminder.next_daily(datetime.now(timezone), today)}",
            f"Next review: {Reminder.next_occurance('Sprint review', today)}",
            f"Next retrospective: {Reminder.next_occurance('Sprint restrospective', today)}"
        )
```

And the code of the test:

```
@freeze_time("2023-06-12", tz_offset=2)
def test_reminder_next():
    expected_response = "\n".join([
        f"Next planning: {datetime(2023, 6, 19, 15, 30, tzinfo=timezone_utc2)}",
        f"Next daily: {datetime(2023, 6, 13, 9, 30, tzinfo=timezone_utc2)}",
        f"Next review: {datetime(2023, 6, 15, 14, 45, tzinfo=timezone_utc2)}",
        f"Next retrospective: {datetime(2023, 6, 16, 9, 30, tzinfo=timezone_utc2)}"
    ])
    assert Reminder.reminder_next() == expected_response
```

And the error:

> TypeError: tzinfo argument must be None or of a tzinfo subclass, not type 'type'

By the way `timezone_utc2` is defined by `timezone_utc2 = pytz.timezone('Etc/GMT+2')` (pytz is imported)

I tried replacing `timezone_utc2` by `Etc/GMT+2` : instead of 'type' at the end of the error, I got 'str'.

I tried without anything and it doesn't work either.

If the test is correct, I should have a green bar with '7 passed in x seconds' (I have 6 other tests which are correct)

Comment: The error came of this line : `f"Next daily: {Reminder.next_daily(datetime.now(timezone), today)}",`. I removed `timezone` but now I have this error : `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: I was using the wrong title `reminder_next()`. Now I have `TypeError: str.join() takes exactly one argument (4 given)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use timezone_utc2.localize https://pypi.org/project/pytz/

```
@freeze_time("2023-06-12", tz_offset=2)
def test_reminder_next():
    expected_response = "\n".join([
        f"Next planning: {timezone_utc2.localize(datetime(2023, 6, 19, 15, 30))}",
        f"Next daily: {timezone_utc2.localize(datetime(2023, 6, 13, 9, 30))}",
        f"Next review: {timezone_utc2.localize(datetime(2023, 6, 15, 14, 45))}",
        f"Next retrospective: {timezone_utc2.localize(datetime(2023, 6, 16, 9, 30))}"
    ])
    assert Reminder.reminder_next() == expected_response
```